# Calculating the number of rolls of a dice in python

Tags: python

So I'm a beginner programmer and I'm trying to calculate the number of rolls it would take for two dice to add up to the sum of 11. This is the code I tried, but every time I run this, it gives me the output 'None'. What am I doing wrong here?

```
from random import randint

def die_roll1():
    return(randint(1, 6))

def die_roll2():
    return(randint(1,6))

def roll_sum():
    sum = die_roll1() + die_roll2()
    count = 2
    if sum == 11:
        return(count)
    else:
        count +=2
        roll_sum()

print("The number of rolls are: ", roll_sum())
```

Comment: `roll_sum` doesn't return anything (so it returns `None`), when the `sum != 11`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the result of `roll_sum()` in the `else` block. However, consider using a `while` loop instead, as recursion for simpler cases is generally unpythonic:

```
import random
tries = 1
while True:
  a, b = random.randint(1, 6), random.randint(1, 6)
  if a + b == 11:
    winning = [a, b]
    break
  tries += 1
```

Output:

```
22
[5, 6]
```

Comment: If on the first run through the `while`, if `a + b` does equal `11`, then `tries` will be `0`. I would have thought it should be `1`

Comment: @quamrana Ah, I missed that. Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 0):

*Technically*, you simply need to return the count after the **else** portion.  If you roll two non-11s, then the result is never passed recursively through all function calls, so it gets lost in limbo and returns **None**.

However, your code would never produce a number other than 4 in this case because you reset the **count** variable to 2 every time you roll an 11.

This can be fixed by making your **count** variable **global** (outside the function), and then incrementing it inside the function.  This can also be fixed by declaring the variable outside of a **while** loop.

Answer (score 0):

Iterative programs are nearly always more readable than recursive ones, and your program for this problem should definitely be iterative. The other answers give you an iterative solution.
But as nobody has shown you exactly how to correct your own (recursive) program, I'll do that. I think there are a few things you can learn which will help you (and other beginners) in the long run.

Here's the corrected code.

```
from random import randint

def die_roll():
    return(randint(1, 6))  

def roll_sum(count):
    sum = die_roll() + die_roll()
    if sum == 11:
        return(count)
    else:
        count += 2
        return roll_sum(count)
# Call roll_sum with 2 as your initial count 
roll_sum(2)
```

**Explanation**

- When your if statement block has a return statement, your else block should **ALWAYS** have a return statement too (and so should any elif blocks). If Python doesn't find an explicit return statement (this is what happens in your original program), it returns a special object called None. 
  So you need to make sure that every possible flow through your function leads to a return statement. Preceding your recursive call in your else block fixes this problem.
- Initializing count = 2 inside your roll_sum function results in 2 being assigned to count *every single time that the function is (recursively) called.* This is obviously not what you want. Instead, you can add a function argument called count, which will solve this problem. 
  In your initial call of roll_sum, you will have to pass the initial value of count.
- There is no need of having 2 functions which do exactly the same thing -- die_roll1 and die_roll2. A function is only supposed to encapsulate a functionality. You can instead just call the same function twice. If you want to make it explicit that you have 2 separate dice rolls, you can just add 2 variables.

```
roll1 = die_roll()
roll2 = die_roll()
sum = roll1 + roll2
```

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Here are several simple solutions to calculate the number of times each sum occurs in the rolling of two dice. To answer your specific problem, you would simply need to use the 'Specific Solution' in place of the 'General Solution' below.

```
dice1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
dice2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

totals = []

for num in dice1:
    for roll in dice2:
        sumz = str(num+roll)
        if [sumz, 0] not in totals:
            temp = [sumz, 0]
            totals.append(temp)

for item in totals:
    for num in dice1:
        for roll in dice2:

            # General Solution - sum of all roles
            sumz2 = str(num+roll)
            if sumz2 == item[0]:
                item[1] += 1

            # Specific Solution - only count number of 11's rolled
            if sumz2 == '11':
                if item[0] == '11':
                    item[1] += 1

print(totals)


# Using a dictionary to count

totals = {}

for num in dice1:
    for roll in dice2:
        sumz = str(num+roll)
        if sumz not in totals:
            totals[sumz] = 1
        else:
            totals[sumz] += 1

print(totals)


# using collections

from collections import Counter

# temp list to hold all sumz, including multiple entries of same value
temp = []

for num in dice1:
    for roll in dice2:
        temp.append(num+roll)

# unsorted dictionary of key value pairs
d = Counter(temp)

list_sorted_by_key = []
for i in sorted (d):
    temp2 = (i, d[i])
    list_sorted_by_key.append(temp2)

print(list_sorted_by_key)
```